# ProxyPass within plesk 10/11

Tags: redirection, apache-http-server, minecraft, plesk

I would like to redirect some folder within apache2.

My webserver uses with plesk 11.

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/webbukkit/dynmap/wiki/Setting-up-Dynamic-Map-with-apache2-under-Debian). It says I've got to put redirection rules in this file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. For my webserver this file doesn't even exist. I guess that's because of plesk's website management. However there is only this one file: `000-default`.
I did not modify it!

I also managed to locate the config file for my domain. Which is located here

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.org/conf/last_httpd.include
```

I want to solve my problem with Apache 2 "ProxyPass". Because I think that's the easiest way to solve the redirect.

As I found out, I have to add this line

```
ProxyPass /folder/map/ http://www.google.de
```

This does not work. It exits with error "403 forbidden".
Please give me a hint. Thank you!

Comment: I really don't see in the given config anything about how to open `example.org/mc/map` URL. It handles `/mc/map/up`, `/mc/map/standalone` and `/mc/map/tiles`, but not `/mc/map`.Probably you need to remove temporarily this config and check `example.org/mc/map` again

Comment: @SergeyL You are right. I checked this. I think their tutorial is just wrong. So I edited my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Plesk 10/11:

**1. Create your individual config for apache2**

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/example.org
sudo touch conf/vhost.conf
sudo vim
```

**2. Insert your directives there**

Press <kbd>I</kbd> and insert those lines

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPass /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>:</kbd> and write: `wq` and press <kbd>↵</kbd>

**3. Tell apache to use the config**

```
sudo /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**4. You are done.**

### Plesk 12

- Login as administrator
- Select subscription
- Open in control panel
- Web server settings
- Additional directives for HTTP && Additional directives for HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPass /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
```

Sources:
[oli.new-lan.de](http://oli.new-lan.de/2012/01/plesk-apache-vhost-konfiguration-andern/)
[forum.parallels.com](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=282118)

Comment: For me this resulted in an 404 error when accessing `http://example.org/directory/subdir` (without the trailing `/`) in a browser. To fix it, I created an empty directory `/var/www/vhosts/example.org/directory/subdir/`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct, but I have smth to add:

```
ProxyPass /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
```

No need to add RewriteEngine On here.

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <YOUR_DOMAIN>
```

No need to restart httpd also.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
ProxyPass /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
ProxyPassReverse /directory/subdir/ http://localhost:8123/
```

is right but I had to activate proxy_http module first. By checkbox in Plesk or by terminal.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
service apache2 reload
```

otherwise I've got errors like this in my log:

```
No protocol handler was valid for the URL /myapp. 
If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Comment: The hint to activate/install proxy_http. If you don't have it, you get the mentioned error.